# Find and select cell with a certain date in a row with dates

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find and select a cell in a row of dates in a worksheet called `archief`. The range of the row with dates is  `Sheets("archief").Range("B2:HT2")`. The input for the date I'm looking for is in `Sheets("Rekenblad").Range("B29")`.

After finding the cell in the row of dates, I need to select the cell 1 beneath it. So for example the date I'm looking for is in `B2`, then I need to select `B3`.

After that I want to paste something that I copied before.

How can I do this using VBA? This is the code that I have tried so far.

```
Sub FindCell()
    Dim RowDates As Range
    Dim InputCell As Range
    Set InputCell = Sheets("Rekenblad").Range("B29")
    Set RowDates = Sheets("archief").Range("B2:HT2").Find(What:=InputCell, _
                                                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Please do some resach on `Range.Find` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` and show your attmpet solving your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to this VBA and I already looked for some solutions but I didn't find any yet. This is what I tried so far: 

```Sub FindCell()

  Dim RowDates As Range
  Dim InputCell As Range
  
    Set InputCell = Sheets("Rekenblad").Range("B29")
    Set RowDates = Sheets("archief").Range("B2:HT2").Find(What:=InputCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Select


End Sub```

Comment: Please always put your code into the question itself [edit]. Because in comments they are not really readable. Also what went wrong with your code?

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this forum so thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it you just need to remove the `.Select`.

You might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

```
Sub FindCell()
    Dim InputCell As Range
    Set InputCell = Sheets("Rekenblad").Range("B29")
    
    Dim RowDates As Range
    Set RowDates = Sheets("archief").Range("B2:HT2").Find(What:=InputCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchByte:=False)

    If RowDates Is Nothing Then ' check if find did find something
        MsgBox "Date not found."
        Exit Sub 'nothing was found so we need to abort
    End If
    
    Dim NextDateCell As Range
    Set NextDateCell = RowDates.Offset(RowOffset:=1) 'offset moves from RowDates one down

End Sub
```

Don't ever use `Select` unless you want the user to move there.

When using the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) make sure you specify at least the following parameters:

> The settings for `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte`are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.

Comment: nicely done... Just one thing. It is advisable to use all relevant parameters of `.Find`. Excel has an uncanny habit of using the previous settings when using `.Find` :D

Comment: I tried this but I get the message "date not found". The date in ```Sheets("Rekenblad").Range("B29")``` is the same as in ```Sheets("archief").Range("G1")```

Comment: @SiddharthRout Correct, I didn't see it.

Comment: @Jacco9205 See my edit. And check the parameters of `.Find`.